# iPhone App on iPad not responding to touch at first start

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, touch, orientation

If my iPhone App (not universal) starts in landscape mode on my iPad (3rd gen) it does not respond to any touch until I either press the 1x/2x Button or change the orientation. After that it works as normal.
If I start it on my iPhone 5 in landscape mode, it works like a charm.

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation gives a YES in every View, so I think that's not the problem here.

The first View is a tabbar-view.

Comment: I've got the exact same problem as you but with an iPad 2nd gen. Have you gotten any solutions yet? Since my app is only set to work in landscape it always behaves like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem too on my iPad mini with iOS6.0.1.

What I do to solve the problem is to set the Supported interface orientations to all off in the info.plist.

Next, add the Supported interface orientations (iPad) in info.plist and only add the Potrait (bottom home button) in it.

It should make no difference to the apps orientation provided that you set it properly in the view controller. 
Also, make sure you set a correct initial interface orientation.

It then solves my problem.

Comment: this worked for me. It's unfortunate that you need to have the iPad orientation set, but have the app marked as iPhone only, though, as those values are set automatically by xcode.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are a bit difficult, especially when using Xamarin. This answer does work:

from another question:
[iphone app doesn't respond after starting in landscape orientation on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445452/iphone-app-doesnt-respond-after-starting-in-landscape-orientation-on-ipad)

The comment of Daniel Sandland did solve it for me:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions,

(the C# variant for Xamarin)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be the problem of positioning of UI controls present on your screen.
The controls might be having auto positioning parameters (in XIB) may have been set in such way that the controls goes out of screen.
Try to correct resizing parameters in XIB.

Comment: the controls are perfectly visible, thats the strange thing.